How do I create a member that can accept 2 very similar interfaces?
I currently have two classes that do exactly the same but have differences of a single member.
interface interfaceA {
    VariationA getVariation();
}
interface interfaceB {
    VariationB getVariation();
}

public class classC{
    private interfaceA interfaceImpl = new interfaceAImpl();
}
public class classD{
    private interfaceB interfaceImpl = new interfaceBImpl();
}

I'm looking for an elegant way to unite classA with classB
P.S.,
I have Lombok and Spring framework capabilities available.

Consider making your code and question more "concrete", showing more of a real-world code example, including the methods of the interfaces, so that we can see how they are similar and how they are different.

There's not enough info to make an informed solution in case of any edge cases, but at a first glance, it looks like you could just combine the interfaces into a generic interface with a generic getVariation()

Re: "an elegant way to unite classA with classB" - what are these classes - 1) not posted; 2) you meant interfaceA and interfaceB; or 3) you meant classC and classD ( or 4) ??? )

I'm not the owner of the interfaces, redia are... RedisAsyncCommands and RedisAdvancedClusterAsyncCommands

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You haven't included the code for VariationA or VariationB, but you can do something like this:
interface FooInterface {
  public void foo();
}

public class VariationA implements FooInterface {
  public void foo() {
    ...
  }
}

public class VariationB implements FooInterface {
  public void foo() {
    ...
  }
}

And if you don't want VariationA and B to directly implement FooInterface, you can create a subclass, like:
VariationAWfoo extends VariationA implements FooInterface{
  public void foo() {
    ...
  }
}

or you can create a facade class, like this
public class Facade implements FooInterface {
  VariationA a;
  VariationB b;
  public VariationContainer(VariationA a) {
   this.a = a;
  }
  public VariationContainer(VariationB b) {
   this.b = b;
  }

  public void foo() {
   //do something with a or b
  }
}


Unfortunately, your question is not really straightforward but let's consider you want to unify classC and classD. You can create a common interface and using generic to handle that.
You should take three steps to do that.

Define an interface with a generic type

    public interface CommonInterface<T> {
        T getVariation();
    }


Now write down your interfaces but let them extend from CommonInterface and implement them in your class

public interface InterfaceA extends CommonInterface<VariationA> {}

public interface InterfaceB extends CommonInterface<VariationB> {}

Let's say you have 2 classes like InterfaceImplementationA and InterfaceImplementationB.
public class InterfaceImplementationA implements InterfaceA {
    @Override
    public VariationA getVariation() {
        return new VariationA();
    }
}

public class InterfaceImplementationB implements InterfaceB {
    @Override
    public VariationB getVariation() {
        return new VariationB();
    }
}


Use getter and setter lombok

@Getter
@Setter
public class UnifiedClass<T> {
    private CommonInterface<T> interfaceImplementation;

    public UnifiedClass(CommonInterface<T> interfaceImplementation) {
        this.interfaceImplementation = interfaceImplementation;
    }
}

